# Find a bijection between two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that there is a bijection mapping between $X^{\Bbb N}$ (sequences of elements of $X$) and a proper subset of itself.

Comment: Is $X$ a vector space? If $X$ is finite, this is clearly not true.

Comment: I think by $X^{\omega}$ they mean the set of functions $f:\mathbb{Z}_+ \to X$ for a finite $X$...?

Comment: Nothing else is given about x. This is the question

Comment: Take X={0,1}. Then X is finite, while X^N has the same cardinality as R , which is uncountable. Therefore, the propositon is wrong.

Comment: It is sufficinet that it is infinte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this answer I will assume $0\in \mathbb{N}$.

Fix some elment $a\in X$ and take $\tilde X= \{a\}\times X^{\mathbb{N} -\{0\}}$, that is all the sequences (=elements of $X^\mathbb N$) that start with $a$.

You can find a bijection between $\tilde X$ and $X^\mathbb N$, say $(x_0,x_1,\ldots) \mapsto (a,x_0,x_1,\ldots)$.

You can also show $|\tilde X|=|X^\mathbb N|$ and deduce that such bijection exists, without explicitly finding it.

**Please note** that this holds iff $X\not=\{a\},\emptyset$, that is $X$ has more than one element. If it has exactly one element, then $|X^\mathbb N|=|(a,a,a,\ldots)|=1$ and clearly the proposition is not true (in that case, $\tilde X$ is not a proper subset of $X^\mathbb N$) . Also, the same hapens if $X=\emptyset$ (in that case, you can't define $\tilde X$ the way I did as there is no $a\in X$). So we need $|X|\geq 2$ for this argument.